# Encrypted SAML Assertion

Tags: encryption, certificate, saml-2.0, assertion

Based on my reading, we use both the certificate and a public key to encrypt the assertion, and to decrypt the assertion, we have to use the private key to decrypt it.  I do not want to share my private key with my client, Is there other way to not provide the private key?  I want to keep the private key, encrypt my assertion and give the response to my client, the client will use the public key instead to decrypt my message, does this thinking work at all?

Thank you.

Comment: What you probably should be looking for is a tutorial on public key cryptography. Perhaps you can edit your question with more information on what you've been reading.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is just a very long number and is used to decrypt. The public key is just a very long number and is used to encrypt. Only the corresponding private key can decrypt what a public key encrypts.

A certificate ([X509 public certificate](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-an-x-509-certificate/)) wraps the public key and the private key in identity information. The certificate is digitally signed by a certificate authority to say, to the best of its knowledge that the key belongs to who it says it belongs to.

You give your public key to your client. They verify it's from you by checking the digital signature on its certificate and they encrypt information with your public key.

You then decrypt that information using the corresponding private key which you never ever give to anyone.

It's all about [Public Key Infrastructure (PKI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to keep the private key, encrypt my assertion and give the response to my client, the client will use the public key instead to decrypt my message

From the text I assume you're implementing a SAML IdP.

Actually you need the client's SP public key to encrypt the assertion for the SP. And then sign the assertions with your (IdP) private key.

The SP must validate the SAML assertion signature with the IdP's public key and then they may decrypt the assertions with their SP private key.

So indeed the private keys stay with their owners.